# Stylesheet rendering issues on LAMP/Ubuntu

Tags: php, css, sql

I have developed a database using PHP/SQL that is working well on my cloud space but when I set up LAMP on Ubuntu and copied everything it's like the stylesheet is being ignored.

I've verified the permissions are set appropriately and can even link to the style sheet through the browser. I suspect it has something to do with the MIME type but I'm not even sure how to correct that.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Viewing style.css through the browser and pulling up page info shows text/css as the MIME type.

Inspecting various elements doesn't show any styles from my stylesheet.

Checked the access and error logs and they are pretty unremarkable. Functionally the site still works it's just ugly as all heck without the styling. This is really throwing me I'm wondering if I should just wipe everything and start over. I'm very new and self taught would using XAMPP or AMPPS be better for a beginner?

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and look at the Network and Console tabs for any errors

Comment: Network shows GET to index.php and all the image files. Console shows an error on one of the image files because I deleted it and forgot to comment it out of the code. One possibly interesting thing is content-type is showing text/html and has no reference to css or php or anything like that.

Comment: Is style.css in the same folder than your index.html or index.php? When you say that you can link to the stylesheet through the browser is that you could load with the full, absolute url? With localhost?

Comment: Yes style.css and index.php reside in the same folder. When viewing the html code in the browser via 'view page source', style.css is clickable as it's shown in the link tag. When I click on it style.css code is shown in a new tab in the browser.

Comment: when you inspect any element on the page? can you see styles are getting attached to it? If yes, then try to change something from inspecting CSS, see if changes showing.

Comment: I don't see any styles from my stylesheet. When I open the head tags to view where the stylesheet is linked in the inspection window, it's all grey, no color-code. Is this significant?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is check and double check your code. smh. I feel so stupid the I guess I downloaded style.bak file from my cloud server and saved it as style.css. None of my stylings were named properly except * and body :/. I "checked" the syntax of style.css once in the very beginning of my troubleshooting process but just breezed through it scanning for brackets I guess. Rookie move - I hang my head in shame. Days worth of chasing my tail over something so.... well at least I learned a lot about Apache XD

On that note I want to mention that this site and all of the incredibly skilled people that answer questions here are INVALUABLE. I don't know how many times searching this site has helped me in my process of self-learning PHP and SQL but it's very well could be over a thousand. I salute all of the contributors, thank you so much.